# How does one derive the parallel transport rule for a spinor?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

While I do not have a very deep understanding about what a [spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) is. It seems to be some sort of "squareroot of a vector" to me. Assuming some version of equivalence principle:

**How does one derive the [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) rule for the spinor?**

I could only [google](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-010-0862-4_6) this but it's behind a paywall.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection